# What type of material is this shower base?

Tags: shower, cleaning, materials

I have a shower in my apartment with a pretty dirty base. I'd love to give it a real good cleaning, I haven't tried much yet, but I think the best strategy would be to determine the material of the base and then learn about cleaning that material.

[image]
[image]
[image]

- What can I do to determine the material?
- Does it even matter, is there some kind of cleaning solution I can use no matter that material?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [terrazzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrazzo), but it's really hard to tell the details. Stone chips are easy to identify, the material between them is tricky. It can be:

- some kind of resin / polymer
- concrete

Terrazzo is known to be made with both of these, and it is not possible to tell them apart just by looking on photos. So you probably need to ask for cleaning fluid safe for both.

It's tempting to assume resin because it's shower, but I did see concrete-based terrazzo in bathrooms, too.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds like the winning answer! [This looks almost exactly the same as my shower pan](http://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=98250) and he claims it to be Terazzo. I'll go with cleaning solution safe for both.

Comment: If it is terrazzo, it might be possible to polish it out. I believe stone finishing tools can be used, therefore stone countertop fabricators may be able to give some insight.

Comment: @Jack That's outside os my experience, but I advise caution. I've seen terrazzo with missing stones in it :( and it's hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

That is concrete with exposed aggregate you can use anything that is approved for cleaning that including some acid based products.

Comment: I beg to differ with you on it being concrete. I have seen these before, I don't know if it is an epoxy or some other resin, but it is something like that.

Comment: I'm sure you could be very well right I was just judging by the aggregate that was visible if that's what it is I have seen concrete shower pans that looked just like that as well but you are correct they do use a resin to build up shower pans with also